# is scipy.stats.linregress deterministic?

Tags: python, scipy

By deterministic I mean if given the same `x,y`, is `scipy.stats.linregress()` guaranteed to get the same results regardless of random seed/platform/hardware/etc.?

Answer (score 1):

`scipy.stats.linregress()` calculates a linear least-squares regression, which is a deterministic algorithm, so the answer is yes.

You can convince yourself by looking at the [source code of the function](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.6.1/scipy/stats/_stats_mstats_common.py#L16).